# Find distinct tree hierarchy

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have DB with following tables and relations:

```
Trunk (1..n)    Branch (1..n)   Twig (0..n) Leaf
```

Branch, Twig and Leaf have similar columns.
For example Twig has columns:

```
id, branchID, name, description, key1, key2, key3
```

I don't care about name and description, but I care about key 1 - 3

My goal is to find distinct tree structure (or hierarchy) and get Trunk IDs that follow same tree configuration.

Same tree configuration means:

- each Trunk has same number of Branches (1 - n)
- Branches have same key values (but can have different name and description)

  - each Branch has same number of Twigs (1 -n)
  - Twigs have same key values (but can have different name and description)

    - each Twig has same number of Leafs (0 - n)
    - Leaf have same key values (but can have different name and description)

When I join all tables (Trunk, Branch, Twig and left join Leaf) and group them by relevant key values
I only get Trunks that share a specific Trunk-to-Leaf combination but they might differ in another branch (or miss it altogether)

Now I have 500 Trunks, while there might be only 8 different tree configurations.

My expected result would be: TrunkID - TreeConfiguration (1 - 8)

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Just pondering turning the problem upside down. What if you build a table of `EquivalentLeaves( EquivalentLeafId GUID, LeafId Int )` that groups all of the "equivalent", i.e. matching key values, leaves under a common GUID. Repeat for twigs where "equivalent" means a common set of leaves, i.e. leaf GUIDs and counts match. Then branches, trunks, forests, ... . (No special reason to pick a GUID, I just wanted something distinctly different from the typical identity value.)